# When to update bin folder

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET application (web application as opposed to website), and several class libraries.

Just to make sure, every time a change is made to the class library, do I need to recompile and refresh/update the dll from thbe bin folder of my web app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Everytime you change a class used by your website code, you need to redeploy it.